# How to set an Android selector without write a xml?

Tags: android

For example:

`<ImageView
          ---
            android:src="@drawable/settings_normal" 
---
/>`

Could I directly write something like src="android:state_pressed="true" ..."

or I just can write a selector in the xml file?

If anyone knows the answer it would be greatly
appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In code, have a listener with a toggle flag.
Start playing with it

```
onclick()
{
if(red)
{
//change color
 green=true;
 red=false
}
else
{
 //change color
 red=true;
  green =false
 }

 }
```